How does PostgreSQL display the estimated number of rows in ANALYZE?
I executed query 1c.sql in JOB When the parallel worker is set to 1, its estimated number of rows is accurate (in fact, it is not necessary to estimate because there is no selection on this table).
{ +
  "Node Type": "Seq Scan",  
  "Parent Relationship": "Outer",        
  "Parallel Aware": false,  
  "Relation Name": "movie_info_idx",     
  "Alias": "mi_idx",        
  "Startup Cost": 0.00,     
  "Total Cost": 21735.35,   
  "Plan Rows": 1380035,     
  "Plan Width": 50,         
  "Actual Startup Time": 0.012,          
  "Actual Total Time": 117.952,          
  "Actual Rows": 1380035,   
  "Actual Loops": 1         
}   

But when the worker num is 3, The estimated row becomes strange.
{      
  "Node Type": "Seq Scan",          
  "Parent Relationship": "Outer",   
  "Parallel Aware": true,          
  "Relation Name": "movie_info_idx",
  "Alias": "mi_idx",
  "Startup Cost": 0.00,
  "Total Cost": 13685.15,           
  "Plan Rows": 575015, 
  "Plan Width": 8,  
  "Actual Startup Time": 0.016,     
  "Actual Total Time": 45.693,      
  "Actual Rows": 460012,            
  "Actual Loops": 3 
},

It looks like the plan rows and actual rows are divided by two different number of workers. How does this happened?
The plan rows is just 1.25x to the actual rows, which means plan_rows x 4 equals to actual_rows x 5.
The version of PostgreSQL is 12.5.

It assumes work will not be distributed exactly evenly, due to variable row density for example. Since the plan is limited by the slowest worker, it deals with this by inflating the row estimate by a fraction.
The gather node reports the exact total actual row count.  If there are intervening steps between the seq scan and the gather which will alter this row count, then you could add VERBOSE to the EXPLAIN options so that each worker separately reports its actual rows and then you could sum those reports to get the total.
The gather node should report the plan rows without the "fudge factor" being applied.  If that doesn't work for you because there are nuisance steps between the seq scan and the gather, you could redo the plan with max_parallel_workers_per_gather set to zero and then the seq scan node itself would report a plan rows which is unaffected by the parallel fudge factor.  In this case, the EXPLAIN does not need to include ANALYZE, since you are only looking at the estimates and not the actuals.

Thanks for answering! So is there a way to get the exactly total actual row and plan row in a parallel setting?
